# Like/Dislike on Ruby on Rails with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am working on a project (Pinterest clone) which has a model **User** and a model **Pin**. I am using the *acts_as_votable* gem for users to upvote or downvote images uploaded which I call 'pins'. Everything is working well but I am refreshing the page for the like/dislike system to make an update to the likes/dislikes counter.

I would like to use AJAX so that I don't need to refresh the page.

The **Pin** controller has this:

```
def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to root_path   
end

def  upvote
    @pin.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
end

def downvote
    @pin.downvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
end

private

def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :image) 
end

def find_pin
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
end
```

I am using haml, and the **Pin -> show** view has the following:

```
#pin_show.row
 .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
    .panel.panel-default
        .panel-heading.pin_image
            = image_tag @pin.image.url
        .panel-body
            %h1= @pin.title
            %p.description= @pin.description
        .panel-footer
            .row
                .col-md-6
                    %p.user
                        Submitted by
                        = @pin.user.name
                .col-md-6
                    .btn-group.pull-right
                        = link_to like_pin_path(@pin), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do
                            %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart-empty
                                = @pin.get_upvotes.size

                        = link_to dislike_pin_path(@pin), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do
                            %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-thumbs-down   
                                = @pin.get_downvotes.size   
                        - if @pin.user == current_user      
                            = link_to "Edit", edit_pin_path, class: "btn btn-default"
                            = link_to "Delete", pin_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-default"
```

And my routes.rb has this:

```
resources :pins do
member do
    put "like", to: "pins#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "pins#downvote"
end
```

end

How do I implement AJAX when I have this approach. I am new to rails and I am pretty much stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Rails' unobtrusive Javascript will listen to links with `data-remote=true` and submit those as js requests.

```
= link_to like_pin_path(@pin), method: :put, data: { remote: true }...
```

These requests will come in to your controller as format js, so your controller actions don't need to redirect if it's format js.

```
def  upvote
  @pin.upvote_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js { render 'vote' }
  end
end
```

That will upvote the @pin for you. But if you want to show feedback on the click, you'll need some js. You could have the `upvote` method render a js template that re-renders the template:

**views/pins/vote.js.erb**

```
$(function() { 
  $('span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart-empty').text("<%= @pin.get_upvotes.size %>");
  $('span.glyphicon.glyphicon-thumbs-down').text("<%= @pin.get_downvotes.size %>");
});
```

**EDIT: Debugging**

If the Javascript isn't doing what you expect, there are a few ways to figure out what's wrong.

**vote.js.erb**

```
$(function() { 
  var upvotes = "<%= @pin.get_upvotes.size %>";
  var downvotes = "<%= @pin.get_downvotes.size %>"
  debugger;
});
```

If you have the Javascript console open, the debugger will pause execution and allow you to insert the jQuery manually. You'll have access to `upvotes` and `downvotes` and you can paste in `$('.glyphicon-heart-empty')` and make sure that finds the right element.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the changes that you stated, but the counters are not showing the change(feedback as you aforementioned) in 'real time'. When I refresh the page, that is when the counter figure changes. However the server is showing that the vote 'has been casted'. Could I be missing something?

Comment: First, make sure that the javascript is firing. Put an alert or a console.log in the anonymous function. If it's not firing, make sure both your upvote and downvote actions are rendering 'vote' and that there's not a server error. If the js is firing, then it's just a matter of tweaking the jQuery.

Comment: "Put an alert or a console.log in the anonymous function". How do I do this and what do you mean if you say I should make sure that javascript is firing? As far as I checked the server, I don't see any error and the server log is showing the rendering of the vote.js.erb

Comment: I see that your questions is been solved thanks to @evanbikes I think he deserve the Green Check mark beside his answer. Thanks.